# What does "go fast" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "will be lost fast"?

This link doesn't help, I think.

> "To any ordinary person, $3 trillion sounds like an awful lot of money. But if a bubble bursts in an economy the size of China's, the money **goes fast**. More to the point, China would have little incentive to defend the Yuan in the case of a burst bubble. The easiest way to deflate the (real) value of assets in China would be to just let the currency take the cut."

Source: https://www.forbes.com/sites/salvatorebabones/2018/05/24/china-is-sitting-on-3-trillion-in-currency-reserves-but-is-that-enough/#24a17a575fce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no Economy expert but I think that when we are talking about a **bubble burst**,
we are talking about the **lost** of value. Money is not lost or spend, it doesn't dissapear, money **lost** its value because **prizes increase** at a quick [**fast**] rate. You may have the **same amount of money** but you can buy **less** things because you can not afford some prizes.

So, I partially agree with @Jason Bassford

> *goes fast = the money will quickly disappear (be spent)*

but this context is a bit more complex.

According to Oxford Dictionary

[**bubble**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bubble)

> Used to refer to a significant, usually rapid, increase in asset
>   prices that is soon followed by a collapse in prices and typically
>   arises from speculation or enthusiasm rather than intrinsic increases
>   in value.

From Cambridge Dictionary

**[burst someone's bubble](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/burst-someone-s-bubble)**

> to say or do something that shows someone that their beliefs are
>   false, or that what they want to happen will not happen